# tm_wday returns a large integer outside 0-6 range

Tags: c++, c++11, time.h

In using the `tm` structure in `c++`, i get values of `tm_wday` that are large integers (e.g. 4199040, much larger than the expected 0-6 range: ). Why would this happen? All the other values such as the year, month etc. are correct.

I have seen previous questions where the weekday seems to be calculated wrongly,i.e. is a different value within the 0-6 range than expected due to time zone differences etc. but I am baffled as to why i would get such a big number instead? It doesn't seem to be a memory location either (not a hex format number).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>


struct tm get_time(std::string timestamp_string = "2019.08.16D11:00:00"){

    struct tm tm;
    int hh, mm;
    int MM, DD, YY;
    float ss;
    const char * timestamp = timestamp_string.c_str();
    if (sscanf(timestamp,"%d.%d.%dD%d:%d:%f", &YY,&MM, &DD,&hh, &mm,&ss) != 6) std::cout<<"oops";

    tm.tm_year = YY - 1900;  // Years from 1900
    tm.tm_mon = MM - 1; // Months form January
    tm.tm_mday = DD;
    tm.tm_hour = hh;
    tm.tm_min = mm;
    tm.tm_sec = ss;
    tm.tm_isdst = 0;
    return tm;

}

int main(){
    struct tm tm = get_time("2019.08.16D11:00:00");
    std::cout<<"Year is: "<<tm.tm_year<<std::endl; //119 - is correct
    std::cout<<"Month since Jan is: "<<tm.tm_mon<<std::endl; //7 - is correct
    std::cout<<"Weekday is: "<<tm.tm_wday<<std::endl;//4199040- why is this so large?

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking around some more, it is expected that after a `tm` structure is defined, you run the function `mktime()` with a reference to the instance in order to update derived values such as `tm_wday`. So the fixed `main()` function should be:

```
int main(){
    struct tm tm = get_time("2019.08.16D11:00:00");
    mktime(&tm); //needs to be called to update derived values such as tm_wday
    std::cout<<"Year is: "<<tm.tm_year<<std::endl; //119 - is correct
    std::cout<<"Month since Jan is: "<<tm.tm_mon<<std::endl; //7 - is correct
    std::cout<<"Weekday is: "<<tm.tm_wday<<std::endl;//shows 5 now - is correct
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In this case, `mktime()` should be moved inside of `get_time()` before it calls `return tm;`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Agree, that is a more robust way to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Why should it be any other value?

You never set it to anything.

So, it retains its initial value, which is *unspecified* since you never initialised the `tm`.

Therefore, it's not just "a large integer": your whole program has undefined behaviour as a result of attempting to read this unspecified value.

---

If you expected it to be automatically set to the appropriate weekday index for the values you entered, that's not how it works. The `tm` is just a collection of values, not a function.

However, you can call `mktime` to do what you need:

> The **mktime()** function modifies the fields of the tm structure as follows: *tm_wday* and *tm_yday* are set to values determined from the contents of the other fields; if structure members are outside their valid interval, they will be normalized (so that, for example, 40 October is changed into 9 November); *tm_isdst* is set (regardless of its initial value) to a positive value or to 0, respectively, to indicate whether DST is or is not in effect at the specified time. Calling **mktime()** also sets the external variable *tzname* with information about the current timezone.

([ref](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime))

Comment: Thanks - i guess i was expecting behavior similar to python’s datetime module where you can simply do this :  datetime.datetime(2019,8,16).weekday()

Comment: Instead of guessing, refer to the documentation